# Updating dictionary within loops

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in which keys are "group_names" and values are gene_lists.

I want to update each dictionary with a new list of genes by looping through a species_list.

Here is my pseudocode:

```
groups=["group1", "group2"]
species_list=["spA", "spB"]
    
def get_genes(group,sp)
    return gene_list

for sp in species_list:
    for group in groups:
        gene_list[group]=get_genes(group,sp)
        gene_list.update(get_genes(group,sp))
```

The problem with this code is that new genes are replaced/overwritten by the previous ones instead of being added to the dictionary. My question is where should I put the following line. Although, I'm not sure if this is the only problem.

```
gene_list.update(get_genes(group,sp))
```

The data I have looks like this dataframe:

```
data={"group1":["geneA1", "geneA2"],
      "group2":[ "geneB1","geneB2"]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).T
```

The data I want to create should look like this:

```
data={"group1":["geneA1", "geneA2", "geneX"],
      "group2":[ "geneB1","geneB2", "geneX"]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).T
```

So in this case, "gene_x" refers to the new genes obtained by the get_genes function for each species and finally updated to the existing dictionary.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append to the list in the dictionary entry, not assign it.

Use `setdefault()` to provide a default empty list if the dictionary key doesn't exist yet.

```
for sp in species_list:
    for group in groups:
        gene_list.setdefault(group, []).extend(get_genes(group, sp))
```

Comment: Okay good, now it solved the problem but created another one.

Comment: spA=["geneA1", "geneA2"]
spB=["geneB1","geneB2" ]

b={'group1': [ spA ], "group2": [ spB] }
pd.DataFrame(b)

a={'group1': spA , "group2": spB}
pd.DataFrame(a)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to show there.

Comment: So now my data frame looks like a. But I want it to be like b.

Comment: You asked how to update the dictionaries as you showed. My code should do that. If you're not getting the desired dataframe from that, it's a different problem.

Comment: the problem is the dictionaries are not updated by values instead they are updated by a list of values.

Comment: Does `get_genes()` return a string or a list?

Comment: Use `.extend()` instead of `.append()` if it returns a list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239170/discussion-between-zkrt-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to append new gene to each key, in order to do that:

```
new_gene = "gene_x"
data={"group1":["geneA1", "geneA2"], "group2":[ "geneB1","geneB2"]}

for value in data.values():
    value.append(new_gene)    

print(data)
```

You can also use defaultdict where you can append directly (read the docs for that).

Comment: Where is `groups` in this answer?